# How to create an image whose alpha value changes according to a curve through time in node-editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency, keyframes, timeline

I connected an image-node with a composite-node and connected a value-node into the alpha of the composite-node. I changed the values and the image changed its transparency.

Then, I connected the time-node into the alpha of the composite-node instead of the value-node, changed the graph of the time-node into an oscillating wave and when I clicked on different frames in the time-line the transparency also changed according to the curve.

**So far so good, here the problem:**
My goal is to make an animation of a picture whose alpha-value is oscillating along with a curve through time. I tried to apply keyframes on the time-node but it does not seem to be possible.

Comment: A screen capture will help the explanation.

Comment: the keyframes worked great in the mixer-node, but those were only two values, here I have a whole hand-drawn curve in the timenode, i tried randomply to press the I-key onto the values directly on the time-node, but no effect like with the values in the mixer-node....i do not understand it.

Comment: wait, I guess I got it, I do not have to put any keyframes only press onto the "animation" button.